# Evaluate $A=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b \operatorname{cotan}\left(\alpha x\right) \cos(n x) dx$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

Evaluate the limits
$$A=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b \operatorname{cotan}\left(\alpha x\right) \cos(n x) dx$$
and
$$B=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^b \operatorname{cotan}\left(\alpha x\right) \sin(n x) dx$$
where $[a,b]$ included in $\operatorname{cotan}\left(\alpha x\right)$ domain. My approach, in both cases, is to integrate these by parts. In this way, we obtain an expression as:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{S_n}{n}$$
where $S_n$ is bounded. Thus: $A=B=0$. I would like to know if my approach is correct, please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say "$[a,b]$ is included in the cotan$(ax)$" domain, do you mean that the function is not singular on this interval?

Comment: Yes, @Chappers.

Comment: Then what you have done is fine, since the integrand is continuous, so you can use integration by parts, and the new integrand is bounded, so the integral is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Check [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: Please, could you explain how? Thanks in advance @science.